# Why was "Emulators or external tools that support backtracking like in Nestopia" delted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

With the new reputation log, I noticed the question of the title "Emulators or external tools that support backtracking like in Nestopia" which I replied to is gone. I slightly remember it wasn't the greatest question ever, but it wasn't bad either, so why was it deleted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably because it was a request for a recommendation or list.

Emulator-rec is no better than Game-rec.

Comment: Good point, but then why wasn't it simply closed as "too general"?

Comment: A few reasons. 1) Because it isn't 'too general', it's *off topic*. We don't do recommendations here. Full stop. 2) Closure isn't meant to be a permanent case (aside from the special case of duplicates). Think of closure as purgatory, where good questions can be redeemed and reopened with a little judicious editing, and where bad questions wait to be deleted. The point of the 'closed' status is to give the community a chance to see the question and contest it's 'marked for deletion' status, either by fixing it, or by voting to reopen it as is.

Comment: purgatory is a rather good description, I didn't see it that way before, thanks!